Using productFlavors correctly in android studio
How can i create product flavours properly. I'm importing a project from github but decided to start a new project and copy the files individually considering that changing names of the directory throws a bunch of exeption.
And is there a more viable method to change package names?
productFlavors {
    system {
        dimension = "source"
    }
    database {
        dimension = "source"
    }
}

Tried opening build view but it didnt show any options to add the product flavor

So does your question is How to change package name with respect of flavours ?

@BobSmith No. It's about how to add product Flavours.

consider reading post https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants
